# Laravel one column sorting 1 column and infinitive nesting

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have categories,subcategories,categories of subcategories that are all in one table. Table looks like this

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->default(NULL);
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')-   >onDelete('cascade');
$table->string('name');
$table->timestamps();
```

controller

```
$projects = Projects::pluck('post','parent_id');
```

view

```
  @if (count($projects) > 0)
    <ul>
      @foreach ($projects as $project)
       @include('partials.project', $project)
      @endforeach
    </ul>
   @endif
```

partials.project

```
<li>{{ $project['name'] }}</li>
    @if (count($project['children']) > 0)
     <ul>
       @foreach($project['children'] as $project)
        @include('partials.project', $project)
       @endforeach
     </ul>
    @endif
```

I marked children where I would want that subcategories and categories from them go. How can I pull this off

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/etrepat/baum, I think it should solve your problem and it also has a nice description of how it works exactly.  It would require a little bit different structure on your table though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have defined the relation:

```
// Project.php
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

you can call the view as

```
// ProjectController.php
public function showNested()
{
    $max_level = 3; // the max nesting level you will support

    $eager_load = implode('.', array_map(function () { return 'children'; }, range(1, $max_level)));

    $projects = Project::where('parent_id', null)->with($eager_load)->get();

    return view('projects', compact('projects', 'max_level'));
}
```

parent view:

```
// projects.blade.php
<ul>
    @foreach($projects as $project)
        @include('partials.project', [
            'project' => $project,
            'level' => 1,
            'max_level' => $max_level
        ])
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

partial view:

```
// partials/project.blade.php
<li>{{ $project->name }}</li>

@if ($level < $max_level && $project->children->count())
    <ul>
       @foreach($project->children as $child)
           @include('partials.project', [
               'project' => $child,
               'level' => $level + 1,
               'max_level' => $max_level
           ])
       @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

---

(Update)

Explanation on

`$eager_load = implode('.', array_map(function () { return 'children'; }, range(1, $max_level)));`

You know what eager loading is, right? Basically, what I wanted is to pre-fetch from the database all nested projects, up to the selected level. So, if you do `->with('children')` it will get the projects and their direct children. If you do `->with('children.children')` it will get the top-level projects and 2 levels of children.

So, breaking it down:

```
$max_level = 3;
// variable

range(1, $max_level);
// gives [1, 2, 3]

array_map(
  function () { return 'children'; },
  range(1, $max_level)
);
// gives ['children', 'children', 'children']

implode('.', array_map(function () { return 'children'; }, range(1, $max_level)));
// gives 'children.children.children'
```

Comment: thank you it works. if it's not a problem can you explain this line of code "implode('.', array_map(function () { return 'children'; }, range(0, $max_level - 1)));" .

Comment: Thank you for the explanation it will be great help in the future